# alternative to MAILTO

Tags: javascript, outlook, html-email, mailto

I need to open an Outlook email window from the browser and prepopulate it with some HTML content.   I currently use ActiveX for that, but that, of course, only works in IE.

Are there any better options ?

Comment: Why are you asking for an "alternative to mailto" when `mailto:` is the cross-browser method of doing what you need?

Comment: @AdrianWragg — You can't send HTML content in a `mailto:`

Comment: I have to wonder if the solution is simply not to send HTML email.

Comment: The solution to most problems involving the interaction of webpages and email is to send the email yourself and not ask the client to do it.

Comment: @Quentin I'd missed the "HTML" part of "HTML content", you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailto and set subject/content with it.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=This is the subject&body=This is the default content">Send mail</a>
```

You can even use html but you would have to url encode it and for it to work, depends on the email client.

Comment: "This is the default content" is not "HTML content" as requested.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, you can use HTML content, you just need to urlencode it first.

Comment: You're wrong. [http://jsbin.com/IkUtuTo/1/](http://jsbin.com/IkUtuTo/1/) treats the HTML as plain text. It doesn't matter which email client you use.

Comment: Can an EML file be opened from Outlook client ?